# why index defined in the table not being used by the query optimizer? (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, key, optimization

I have the below schema

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `d` date NOT NULL,
  `y` year(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `y` (`y`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARSET=utf8;
```

when i run "EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test where y = '2010';"

Although there is an index defined in the table for column "y", it is not being used by the query optimizer.

What could be the reason?

Comment: How many rows are in the table?  MySQL is not obligated to use an index just because it is available.

Comment: what ? year is built-in MYSQL type , check this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/year.html

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try this command? "EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test where year = 2010;"

Comment: ;-) , thanks , no , i use EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM test where y = '2010';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL must find it worth using the index.

This is usually the case when the dbms expects to find just a few records. Even something as low as 10% or even 5% of all records may be regarded as too many and the dbms decides then better to scan through the whole table instead of having to muddle its way through the index.

So the answer is: MySQL doesn't consider it appropriate to use an index here. It thinks that a full table scan is probably faster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but how Mysql appropriate that?my question is that ,  because I say in schema that I want to have a year as a key and used that on where close so it seem that Mysql must use and index.

Comment: You have 70000 records in your table. This is not much and can be read very fast. Using an index can be very slow on the other hand. How many different years are there in your table? If there are 70000 different years, I would definitely say use the index. With 10000 years, I would still say use the index. But with only 100 different years for instance I would assume that a full table scan is faster for being so much simpler.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT y FROM test;
+------+
| year |
+------+
| 2008 |
| 2009 |
| 2010 |
| 2011 |
| 2012 |
| 2013 |
| 2014 |
+------+

Comment: Only seven different years. This is certainly much too few to have the dbms consider using the index. If you had to underline certain lines in a book and you knew that would be about every seventh line, would you simply read line by line or would you consult another book listing matching pages and lines, so you'd have to switch between the two books all the time? Probably the former, and so does MySQL.